# I was asked to write a bill of sale for 6000 dollars over the amount actually paid

Tags: insurance

I was asked to write a bill of sale for 6k over the actual amount paid. The guy wrecked it and apperntly the insurance company is only willing to pay blue book. It is worth about 9k because it's custom but they are only willing to pay him the base value. To me it feels illegal lol but just want to get some insight. Iv decided not to write it for more than was paid but I'm just curious.

Comment: How will you feel when the insurance investigator visits you? Even if not illegal (probably is illegal), you could have been subjected to civil liabilities.

Comment: Also what possible benefit would you get by helping this guy commit fraud?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1494/

Comment: You need to have a clear question in here somewhere. Also, you need to include more clarifying details about this transaction. Were you buying the car? Selling it? Repairing it? Etc Make it a complete story that we can follow. Regardless though, the answer will be the same: Don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

**This would be insurance fraud.**

It isn't clear exactly what the status of the vehicle is in terms of whether or not you've actually completed the sale, but I don't yet have the reputation to make comments so this answer will assume that you completed the sale on paper but the sale has not yet been registered with your local authorities because if the sale had been registered then there would already be an official record of how much was payed, and the insurance company would presumably be able to access this record without much difficulty.

It isn't immediately clear what difference the amount listed on the bill of sale would make if the insurance company insisted on using the blue book value, but in essence, what you would have done was falsified a document which was intended to be used by the insurance company in order to increase the determined payout for the destroyed vehichle, which would generally constitute fraud. Depending on your jurisdiction, the bill of sale may be considered an official document once filed with your local transportation authority, and so falsifying it would likely be illegal for that reason as well if you were caught.

One potential method that you could employ to legally raise the insurance payout would be to have an assessor look at the vehicle to try and determine what it was worth prior to the accident, although it may be difficult to find someone willing to make an assessment like that. You were right not to falsify the bill of sale.

This question would be better suited for the Law SE than Finance as the actual question is about the act of forging the document rather than the money involved.